# Suppress Chapter number in Table to display "Table #" instead of "Table Chapter#.#"

Tags: tables, numbering

This is my first time working in LaTeX; I am working on my dissertation and I need to rename Tables so that they are numbered as Table 1, Table 2 etc. rather than include the Chapter number in them so as to show up as Table 2.1 for Chapter 2 Table 1.

Additionally, I still want them to show up in the List of Tables so that the List of Table is as follows:

```
                                   List of Tables
Table                                                                   Page
                                  <Chapter Title>
  #                               <Table Caption>                         #
  #                               <Table Caption>                         #
  #                               <Table Caption>                         #
                                  <Chapter Title>
  #                               <Table Caption>                         #
  #                               <Table Caption>                         #
  #                               <Table Caption>                         #
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Shall the table be counted continously then, the counter not reset in a new chapter?

Comment: Thanks, that worked flawlessly, Can I add the Chapter Title to the List of Tables using this?

Comment: No, not directly, but is possible, of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resetting of the table counter and the formatting like `2.1` can be switched off with `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}`.

If the resetting should be kept, but not the formatting, use

`\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}`

rather!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
% Append some code to the definition of `\@chapter`, automatically adding the chapter (short) title to the LoT.
\makeatletter
%\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{{\protect\centering\large\bfseries\thechapter~#1\par\addvspace{10pt}}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{First}
\begin{table}
\caption{Dummy table}
\end{table}


\chapter{Second}
\begin{table}
\caption{Another Dummy table}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just saw that the O.P. added an image to show how the chapter title should be added. I will edit my solution

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you so much!
Can I however have only those Chapters listed that actually have tables in them?

Comment: @user3228698: Yes, but that's another question ;-)

Comment: Follow up: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255582